What is the tag "miner" referring to?
I was just looking through tags and was wondering what miner refers to, because it has no tag wiki, but is a fairly often used tag (56x at time of this question). Does miner refer to persons engaging in mining, to mining software, or to mining hardware?
Closely related: Difference between tags “mining” and “miner”

[miner] and [mining] have been merged.
